# Magento TAF - Cannot find elements

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-enterprise, magento-1.8, taf, mtaf

I am writing tests to test the frontend of a store.

I create products and categories in the admin, this completes as one test.

I then complete a simple test to load the category on the frontend, this completes as one test.

I then try to sort the listing from high to low by price.

This is when the error happens, 'cannot find elements, "dropdowns" - "sort_by_price"

The XPath declared in the YAML is that given by FirePath (Firebug Extension), also the suggested Selenium Firefox Plugin path.

Any suggestions?

YAML

```
category_page_after_reindex:
mca: catalog/category/view/s/%categoryUrl%/id/%id%/
title: %elementTitle%
uimap: &catalogUIMap
    form: &categoryPage
        fieldsets:
          -
            dropdowns:
                sort_by_price: //div[@id='main']/div/div/div/div/div/select
```

FileTest.php

```
//Steps
$this->clickControl('dropdown', 'sort_by_price');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
category_page:
    mca: %categoryUrl%.html
    title: %categoryTitle%
    uimap:
        form: &categoryPage
            fieldsets:
                -
                    category_view:
                        xpath: //div[@class='category-products']
                        dropdowns:
                            show_per_page: //div[@class='toolbar']//div[@class='limiter']/select
                            sort_by: //div[@class='toolbar']//div[@class='sorter']//select
```

source:

- https://github.com/Webinse/Magento-Test-Automation-Framework/blob/master/uimaps/frontend/Category.yml

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can change the xpath and see if it works. Though the xpath is correct, the webdriver cannot find the elements and you will have to try alternative xpath